# webshims FileReader is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to use webshim FileReaderin IE9 , as becouse javascript FileReader does not support in IE9.

my code;

HTML:

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //webshim.setOptions('basePath', '/js-webshim/minified/shims/');

    webshims.setOptions({
        'basePath':'/js-webshim/minified/shims/'
        });

    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext filereader');    



      $('#user-photo').on('change', function (evt) {
            var reader, file;
            reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (evt) {
              var fileData = evt.target.result;

              // fileData is the base64 encoded image
            };

            //use $.prop to access files property
            file = $(this).prop('files')[0];
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
          });       

});
```

I am tring to upload txt file, but when i upload file,   reader = new FileReader(); here throwing exception as FileReader undefined. It works all  other browser except IE9

But Github it says that it works in IE6+.

https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/

can anyone help me regardsing this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it mean it works IE7,8,10? or It does not work at IE

Answer (score 0):

The webshims wiki states that:

*The filereader feature is based on code from https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie*

And from the moxie github link, it shows that:

*XHR2 and File API pollyfills are multi-runtime, which means that they will fallback to Flash and SilverLight (additionally there's Java runtime in production) or even "good old" HTML4, when there are no HTML5 capabilities found in current browser.*

Since IE9 does not [natively](http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader) support Filereader, I suppose it should fallback to either moxie Flash/Silverlight/javasctipt environment

So please check the following:

- Does your file input have the shimable class?

  ```
  <input type="file" class="ws-filereader" id="user-photo" multiple="" accept="image/*" />
  ```
- Is your filereader polyfill loaded?

  ```
  //load the filereader
  webshim.polyfill('filereader');
  ```
- Is your shims folder in the correct path? By default this path is dynamically computed so make sure its using what you explicitly defined

  ```
    webshims.setOptions({
      'basePath':'/js-webshim/minified/shims/'
      });
  ```
- I'm seeing a commented code pertaining to webshim and another to webshims. Is webshims the correct object to use?